# Why can't the Python script be executed during reboot?

Tags: python, cron, reboot

The simple Python script `/home/debian/project/del_video.py` works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import time

today = time.strftime("%w",time.localtime())
video_dir = '/home/ftpuser/ftp_dir/upload/6J078DEGAG56788'
if today == '5':
    for item in os.listdir(video_dir):
        if item != 'DVRWorkDirectory':
            del_dir = os.path.join(video_dir,item)
            os.system('sudo /usr/bin/rm -rf {} '.format(del_dir))
```

Today is Friday (when I post), `/usr/bin/python3   /home/debian/project/del_video.py` delete files in `/home/ftpuser/ftp_dir/upload/6J078DEGAG56788`. I log in to my [IP camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_camera)'s web UI to set the storage, and create a new file in `/home/ftpuser/ftp_dir/upload/6J078DEGAG56788`. I add it in [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview):

```
crontab -e
```

Output:

```
@reboot  /usr/bin/python3   /home/debian/project/del_video.py
```

Reboot, no file deleted, no error information in `cron.log`:

```
Jul 28 09:46:29 debian cron[756]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 28 09:46:31 debian CRON[825]: (debian) CMD (/usr/bin/python3   /home/debian/project/del_video.py)
Jul 28 09:49:06 debian crontab[2218]: (debian) BEGIN EDIT (debian)
Jul 28 09:50:38 debian crontab[2218]: (debian) END EDIT (debian)
Jul 28 09:53:35 debian crontab[2694]: (debian) BEGIN EDIT (debian)
Jul 28 09:55:01 debian CRON[2739]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 28 09:57:56 debian crontab[2694]: (debian) END EDIT (debian)
```

How can I fix it then?

I can write the same function with Bash. In file *project/del_video.sh*:

```
dw=$(date +%w)
video_dir='/home/ftpuser/ftp_dir/upload/6J078DEGAG56788'
if [[ $dw = 5 ]]; then
    for item in $(ls "$video_dir");do
        if [[ $item != DVRWorkDirectory ]];then
           sudo  /usr/bin/rm -rf  "$video_dir"/"$item"
        fi
    done
fi
```

I verified that `del_video.sh` works fine. How can I fix the Python script?

The permissions are already set for user `debian` in file */etc/sudoers*:

```
debian  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Please replace the value (day of the week) according to the real value when you try.

Comment: Did you try to verify *from within the script* that it is is being run? Did you try to verify what strings it is passing to `os.system`?

Comment: The `sudo` has a higher potential to make troubles.

Comment: It woks fine with `python3   /home/debian/project/del_video.py`,can't work when to add in the cron task.

Comment: A lot of things can go wrong. For example no permission to access the directory, no permission to run sudo without specifying a password, spaces in filenames, etc. Write to a log file from your script to see exactly what it's doing and where it failed.

Comment: have you tried `crontab -u root -e`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this two things:

1. os.system() function doesn't use the user's environment variables by default, so sudo might not be in the path.
2. scripts run with sudo will ask for a password, which isn't possible in this situation. Since you've set up passwordless sudo for the debian user, you can run the script with sudo from the crontab:

Crontab

```
@reboot sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/debian/project/del_video.py
```

And the python code should look like something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import time

today = time.strftime("%w",time.localtime())
video_dir = '/home/ftpuser/ftp_dir/upload/6J078DEGAG56788'
if today == '5':
    for item in os.listdir(video_dir):
        if item != 'DVRWorkDirectory':
            del_dir = os.path.join(video_dir,item)
            os.system('sudo /bin/rm -rf {} '.format(del_dir))
```

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ftpuser/ with my script.